# Why do I always go to the error page if there is no error in error.log

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a Vue app which is basically serving static files. I have the simple configuration, which also includes the backend PHP API server.

When I go to `api.localhost` (I added it to the `hosts` file), I do see the backend html page. but when I go to `localhost`, it sends me to the `50x` error page:

```
user       www-data;

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.localhost;
        root /var/www/php-backend/public; 
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
        index index.php;
 
        charset utf-8;
 
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
 
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
        error_page 404 /index.php;
 
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
 
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location /var/www/vue-frontend/dist {
            root   /;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }     

}
events {}
```

When going to `localhost`, I keep seeing the `index.html` page that's inside `/usr/share/nginx/html;` instead of the Vue `index.html`. Why? the `error.log` at `/var/log/nginx` is not showing anything except for `[notice]: signal process started`

Comment: Probably you have another virtual host which is called `localhost` and it takes all the requests. It is bad idea to use such virtual host anyway. Better use another name, and add the required entry into `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: thanks, I will try now. Is it true that I can no longer use the `.dev` domain in development? If so, what is a tld I can use for development?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, I added some new hosts: `myapp.home` and `api.myapp.home`, and still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your location block inside localhost's server block:

```
root /var/www/vue-frontend/dist;
location / {
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

because
`location /var/www/vue-frontend/dist {`
means
`http://localhost/var/www/vue-frontend/dist/index.html` which is not what you want.

Comment: you were close, I did change to `location /` and `root /var/www/vue-frontend/dist;` , but left the `root` directive inside the `location` block and it's working, why did you take it outside the `location` block?

Comment: @BGWay https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block